# How to clear/change the query string in aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, query-string

I have two pages 
1. a.aspx and
2. b.aspx
I pass query string from "b.aspx?save=success" to a.aspx.
 In Page Load of a.aspx I have the following code:

```
Page_Load()
{ 
    if(!Postback)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["save"] != null) 
        {
            noDataFound.InnerHtml = "operation success";
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: On load of a.aspx page I get the message "operation success". This is Ok.But       When I refresh the page again I get the same message as "operation success". How not to display again the same message on page refresh(pressing F5or reload).

Comment: Yes. Page_Load(){ if(!Postback){if (Request.QueryString["save"] != null)
  {noDataFound.InnerHtml = "operation success";}}}

Comment: Because essentially the URL remains the same, that's why you keep seeing the success message.

Comment: Patrick Hofman caught the problem. Great answer by him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function invokeMeMaster() {

    var isPostBack = <%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %> ;

    if (!isPostBack) {

        /* START */
        var query = getQueryParams(document.location.search);

        var p = query.save;
        if (sessionStorage.hits) {
            sessionStorage.hits = Number(sessionStorage.hits) + 1;
        } else {
            sessionStorage.hits = 1;
        }

        if (p == "success" && (sessionStorage.hits) % 2 == 0) {

            document.getElementById("<%=noDataFound.ClientID %>").innerText = "Testing...........";
        }

        function getQueryParams(qs) {
            qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");

            var params = {}, tokens,
            re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

            while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
                params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])] = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
            }

            return params;
        }

        /* END */

    } else {
        document.getElementById("<%=noDataFound.ClientID %>").innerText = "";

    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    invokeMeMaster();
};
```

Comment: Done through client side. Using session was not recommended in .cs page. Though I am using SessionStorage here, it also doesn't solve my problem completely because it just compare the count.

Answer (score 2):

untested solution `(Keeping F5 or Reload of Page in mind)`, may be you have do something like below:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{ 

  if (Request.QueryString["save"] != null && Session["CheckSuccess"] == null)
  { 
    noDataFound.InnerHtml = "operation success";
    Session["CheckSuccess"] = "true";
  } 
  else
    noDataFound.InnerHtml = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way except using Session, because it makes the page heavy.

Comment: I think to maintain the state `Session` is good. It won't create any difference in page loading.

Comment: Or can we store Query string in some collection?

Comment: ofcourse you can maintain `NameValueCollection`. But you will have same key/value every time unless you call your page with different query strings.

Comment: Any Sample you can share?

Comment: [See here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring). Link tells how you can get `NameValueCollection` from querystring.

Comment: F5 will just send the same data as the first time, figuring out that the request is already handled should be on the server. Using the session is a good solution if you want the page to be empty. However showing "operation success" again is just how the web works, adding session stuff will make your pages more complex and probably will introduce nasty bugs in the future. BTW, putting stuff in the query string will make your webapplication vulnerable for xss and injection.

Comment: @peer explained it very well. +1

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of is using the [`IsPostback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to check that.

```
if (!this.IsPostback)
{
    // first try
   if (Request.QueryString["save"] != null)
   {noDataFound.InnerHtml = "operation success";}
}
```

**NOTE: `IsPostback` is not set on refresh, only if clicking a button or something alike triggers the ASP.NET postback action.**

The other thing you could do is set a Session variable then the 'operation succesful' must be shown (probably you determine this in another `Page`.

```
// other page
Session["showSaveMessage"] = true;

// this page
if (Session["showSaveMessage"] == true)
{
    // show message
    Session["showSaveMessage"] = false;
}
```

A third option is to move this client side. Create a javascript action on load of the page. When a specific part is added to the query string (`#showmessage`), you can catch that and show the message ([How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)).

Then redirect to the parameterless version (`#`) by setting the url to the stripped version. Set `window.location.href` or `window.location.search` for that (this won't cause a call to the webserver, since it is all client side).

This circumvents the drawbacks of the first solution, but introduces more code client side. Luckily, ASP.NET MVC has some mechanisms for this. Unfortunately ASP.NET Web Forms doesn't have those.

Comment: OP actually have IsPostback check in place. Strangely it's not working

Comment: I alredy have like this.if (!IsPostBack)
            {
             
                if (Request.QueryString["Save"] != null)
                {  
                    noDataFound.InnerHtml = "operation success";
                }
            }

Comment: @Yahya: added explanation for that. See **note**.

Comment: @PatrickHofman of course user is just refreshing! Good catch.

Comment: Yes Dude.Using Session is not preferred and collection is not working fine.

Comment: @VivekRanjan: well, if you have a better solution... You could pull this onto the client side. I will update the answer.

Comment: @VivekRanjan: Check the third option in my answer. It has some work to do, but I think it is feasible.

Comment: @VivekRanjan: This circumvents the drawbacks of the first solution, but introduces more code client side. Luckily, ASP.NET MVC has some mechanisms for this. Unfortunately ASP.NET Web Forms doesn't have those.